# Sorting Woocommerce products alphabeticaly ASC and DESC

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, woocommerce

I'm facing a problem with the product sorting order. I need them to be sorted alphabeticaly both ways. While I have managed to implement the order options, when I go from ASC to DESC and then back again to ASC, the ordering doesn't work.

Here's my implementation:

```
// Custom sorting options (asc/desc)
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'custom_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 10, 1 );

function custom_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args( $args ) {

  $orderby_value = isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) ? wc_clean( $_GET['orderby'] ) : apply_filters( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', get_option( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby' ) );

  if ( 'asc_list' == $orderby_value ) {
    $args['orderby'] = 'slug name title';
    $args['order'] = 'ASC';
    $args['meta_key'] = '';
  }
  else if ( 'desc_list' == $orderby_value ) {
    $args['orderby'] = 'slug name title';
    $args['order'] = 'DESC';
    $args['meta_key'] = '';
  }

  return $args;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby_options', 'custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby' );

function custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby( $sortby ) {
  $sortby['asc_list'] = 'A-Z';
  $sortby['desc_list'] = 'Z-A';

  return $sortby;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: can you plz try "pre_get_posts"?

Comment: Hi! I'm not sure how I can apply `pre_get_posts` in sorting options...